# Nested SELECT statements in FROM clause SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with this SQL statement. This is going at the end of a procedure I am trying to add to a database named `v3`, and `geneSymbolIn` is defined above. I am getting an error on the last `WHERE` saying that it is unexpected.

```
FROM (SELECT Probe_gene, logFC, adj_P_Value, gene, Study_ID, Group1, Group2  FROM v3.degContrastList WHERE gene = geneSymbolIn) AS CL,
    (SELECT Study_ID, Disease, PMID, Time_Point, Treatment, Raw_Data FROM v3.degContrastListExperiment) AS ET, 
    WHERE CL.Study_ID = ET.Study_ID;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Kyle - please accept answer and vote up, if my solution has solved your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a valid SELECT statement, the [official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) do a pretty good job of outlining the correct syntax.

Comment: Which one is not valid?

Comment: The entire thing, oh...wait, the fact that it is not the complete query, and uses decades old "comma-join" syntax threw me off. The problem is you've got a comma after the second subquery.

Comment: Tiny little commas will be the death of me...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `FROM` statement has a `SELECT` before it.

There is a additional comma after alias `ET` and before `WHERE` clause which is incorrect.

```
FROM (SELECT Probe_gene, logFC, adj_P_Value, gene, Study_ID, Group1, Group2  
      FROM v3.degContrastList 
      WHERE gene = geneSymbolIn) AS CL,
     (SELECT Study_ID, Disease, PMID, Time_Point, Treatment, Raw_Data 
      FROM v3.degContrastListExperiment) AS ET
WHERE CL.Study_ID = ET.Study_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you format the code properly, it's obvious what's wrong with your code.

```
FROM (
    SELECT Probe_gene, logFC, adj_P_Value, gene, Study_ID, Group1, Group2  
    FROM v3.degContrastList 
    WHERE gene = geneSymbolIn
) AS CL,
(
    SELECT Study_ID, Disease, PMID, Time_Point, Treatment, Raw_Data 
    FROM v3.degContrastListExperiment
) AS ET, 
WHERE CL.Study_ID = ET.Study_ID;
```

First of all, no `SELECT` statement. Secondly, there's a comma before `WHERE`.